# Send/get intent extras in fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

the question is in the title.
On normal activity i use:

To send array:

```
b.putParcelable(Activity.EXTRA_ARRAY, xy);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

To get the array:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
Array... xy = b.getParcelable(xy);
```

How to use this in a fragment class?
Sending and recieving this intent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please state the specific problem and read FAQ.

Comment: Use [Master-Detail](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#master-detail-activity) template.

Comment: There's a detailed guide http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html with example

Comment: Thanks but i updated the question to something else now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theres three different scenerios for obtaining a Bundle.

1. If you want to use Bundle arguments to initialize your fragment, you have to use `myfragment.setArguments(mybundle);` when you first create your fragment.
2. If you want your fragment to use the intent that was passed to the activity you can call:

   getActivity().getIntent()
3. If you want only your fragment to intercept an intent then you have to register your fragment using the LocalBroadcastManager. 
   You can see here on how to create this setup: [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Comment: thank you b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(); worked fine for me.